# Facebook shared link does not open in FB iOS App in-app browser

Tags: ios, facebook, apache, hyperlink

We have a website deployed in a Ubuntu 14 server running Apache. The website uses an SSL certificate (so you can access through https) and has a redirection for all the incoming requests without https.

Ok, so the **website is working as expected in desktop browsers and mobile browsers, but, when users tap on the links (from the Facebook iOS app) the in-app browser tries to open the website and returns a message like "Link doesn't work, try again"** (not the exact message in english).

After a lot of research I still don't have a clear idea of what this can happen (just found a couple of unresolved cases on google), so I'd start by looking at the server configuration.

The apache configuration (IP and domains are samples):

```
<VirtualHost 200.200.200.200:80>
    ServerName www.domain.com
    Redirect permanent / https://www.domain.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost domain.com:80>
    ServerName www.domain.com
    Redirect permanent / https://www.domain.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost www.domain.com:443>
    ServerName www.domain.com
    ServerAlias domain.com

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /home/ssl/www.domain.com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/ssl/domain.com.key

    ServerAdmin admin@domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    <Directory /var/www/html>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

The .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

The previous configuration works fine in all browsers, it just doesn't load (doesn't even makes it to Apache access log) when loaded with Facebook iOS in-app browser.

Help is much appreciated! Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Please show code of what you're trying and what happens.

Comment: Thanks @sschale, I've added the content of the server configuration files.

Comment: Run the URL through [a couple of SSL checkers](https://www.google.com/search?q=ssl+check), to make sure everything is o.k. with your certificate.

Comment: Thanks @CBroe, that really helped me dig more into this issue, it turned our Apache SSL configuration needed an additional setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After analyzing the url with the SSL Checker suggested by @CBoroe, I find out that there was a missing intermediate certificate configuration that needed to be added because we're using Apache < 2.4.8 version.

We just had to add the **SSLCertificateChainFile /home/cert_ssl/intermediate.crt** directive. The final SSL part of the code looks like this:

```
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /home/ssl/www.domain.com.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/ssl/domain.com.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /home/ssl/intermediate.crt
```

Hope this helps someone else having this issue. After this change, restart Apache with:

```
service apache2 restart
```

And everything should work fine (you can use the same SSL checker tool to validate it).

Thanks for your time!